# Call a function after an interval when the page is accessed

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

As the title says, I want to call a function every time a page is accessed but only if a specific interval has passed.

To be more precise: One user access the page and the function is called. After x minutes, when the first user accesses the page, the function is called again (no matter if or how many users accessed the page in between or how much time passed, if it's at least x minutes).

I'm using Wordpress and my function is in functions.php

A specific page from the website is calling the function.

I have tried to place a timer in my functions.php to call the function but it breaks my site or make it load forever (I have tried multiple codes and variations)

```
$status=TRUE;
do { 
   myFunction(){
      //code here
   }
   sleep(60); //Sleep 60 seconds
} while($status==TRUE);
```

I think another method is to check the time (server time or set timezone `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`) and call the function after a specific time (IE: xx:00, xx:30) but this will require to check if the function was called before.

Comment: I'd use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) + AJAX for this though. This way you won't have your script locking the execution of PHP for 60 seconds (you really should read the documentation of the [sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function to learn what it actually does) and the page will continue to load normally for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you can use the Wordpress transient API (https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). A transient is a piece of temporary key-value data with a timeout. On each page load, you test whether your transient exists. If not, set it up with an x minute expiration (or any expiration time you want) and execute your code. If another user visits the page within the expiration time, the transient is still there and the code will not be executed:

```
define('TRANSIENT_MY_INTERVAL'); // 5 minute interval for expiration

add_action('wp_loaded', 'do_this_regularly');

function do_this_regularly()
{
  $trans_timeout = 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS; // define your timeout here
  $trans_lock = get_transient('my_transient_lock');
  if (! $trans_lock) { // will be false if expired or not set
    set_transient('my_transient_lock', true, $trans_timeout); // set the lock

    // <- perform your every x minutes action here!
  }
}
```

This code will only execute if people are actually visiting the page, just like with WP cron (https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron). This could be used as well for the same exact purpose - just a matter of preference which one to use.

Comment: I have stumbled across Cron while I was searching, but I wasn't getting any closer. Thank you for the info, everything worked as expected.